# How do I filter on multiple columns using ExtJs grid filter

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, extjs3

I have this code that is allowing me to filter my store on a single column:

```
var events_ds = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                autoLoad: true,
                autoDestroy: true,
                url: '<% $base %>json/events/<% $eventWWN %>.json',
                storeId: 'events_ds',
                idProperty: 'id',
                fields: [ 'id', 'precedence', 'affectedWWN', 'eventType', 'color', 'CollectTime' ],
                listeners:
                         { 'load': function(store) {
                                store.filter( 'color', $_GET['color'] )
                         }
                 }
        });
```

Now, I am wanting to filter on multiple columns.

I was thinking to change the 'listeners' line to this but it is working and I dont see another example where I can use multiple filters - got any suggestions?

```
listeners:
     { 'load': function(store) {
            store.filter( 'color', $_GET['color'] ),
            store.filter( 'priority', $_GET['priority'] )
     }
}
```

Update: This is **ExtJs 3.4**

Answer (score 0):

If you use filters as in a code you posted you will get logical `AND` operation. If you need to have something more complicated you can simply create a filter function like this:

```
store.filter(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
   filterFn: function(item) { 
       return item.get('color') == 'RED' || item.get('priority') == 'low'; 
   }, 
}))
```

Comment: when I plug that code into my data, I get no filtering at all

Comment: I just used:store.filter(Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
   filterFn: function(item) {
       return item.get('color') == $_GET['color'] && item.get('priority') == $_GET['priority'];
   },
}))

Comment: which I should mean that both the color and priority should be those values before it should show correct?  Im just getting the entire set of data with no filters applied

Comment: Yes. It would work like this. Are you on ExtJs4.0x or something else?

Comment: well, it looks like we are on 3.4 so that is our issue

Comment: This might be the reason. My answer was related to ExtJs 4.x